# How to bind Parent and Grand children using BeginCollectionItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to bind a nested list (Parent, Children, Grand children) with BeginCollectionItem? I'm able to bind the Parent and Children but the Grand Children collection is 0. On FireBug, I'm able to see the SurveyAnswers (grand children) but for some reason, they are not binding to the SurveyQuestions (parent of Answers). Survey is the parent of SurveyQuestions.

**Create View**

```
@model Survey

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "requestTypeForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("_RequestTypeForm", Model)
}
```

**_RequestTypeForm Partial View**

```
@model Survey

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    <div id="questions"></div>
    <button id="btnAddQuestion" type="button" />
}
```

**_questionForm Partial View**

```
@model SurveyQuestion

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("SurveyQuestions"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Question)
    <div id="answers"></div>
    <button id="btnAddAnswerToQuestion" type="button" />
}
```

**_answerForm Partial View**

```
@model SurveyAnswer

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("SurveyAnswers"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer)
}
```

**Create Action**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = Survey.New();
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Question Partial View Action**

```
  public PartialViewResult CreateSurveyQuestionView()
  {
      return PartialView("_questionForm", SurveyQuestion.New(true)); // Marking as child
  }
```

**Answer Partial View Action**

```
  public PartialViewResult CreateSurveyAnswerView()
  {
      return PartialView("_answerForm", SurveyAnswer.New(true)); // Marking as child
  }
```

**Create Post Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Survey request)
{
    request.Save();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your `_questionForm` and `_answerForm` partials? (all you have shown is `@Html.Partial("_RequestTypeForm", Model)`) And what is your model?

Comment: Model is Survey (Parent) - @model Survey. I'm calling the _questionForm and _answerForm through Ajax.

Comment: Then show your code and the model. But if `Survey` contains a collection of `SurveyQuestion` and `SurveyQuestion` contains a collection of `SurveyAnswer`, then it cannot work - `@Html.BeginCollectionItem()` only works one level deep.

Comment: Yes, Survey contains a collection of SurveyQuestion and SurveyQuestion contains a collection of SurveyAnswer. Could you suggest another way to make this work?

Comment: If you want performance without ajax calls, look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I8q07y). Otherwise you can look at [this article](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/)